# Thread 1: signal SGABRT

Tags: xcode, swift3

Swift初心者です。 
このたび、iOSのSwiftを使って簡単なブラウザを作ってみたのですが、`AppDelegate.swift`の

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
```

の行で以下のようなエラー文が発生していました。

```
Thread 1:signal SIGABRT
```

原因は何でしょうか？ 
下に`viewController.swift`のソースコードを載せておきます。Xcodeはversion 9.0 beta、Swift3です。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var urlTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var browserWebView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var reloadButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "http://dotinstall.com"
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        self.browserWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func goBack(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func goForward(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func reload(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

以下のようなエラーが発生します。

```
2017-07-07 11:10:19.864054+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111362] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7ffdade10c70, _UIButtonBarStackView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
2017-07-07 11:10:22.310946+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111675] [] network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates
2017-07-07 11:10:24.343312+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111688] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process MyBrowserApp
2017-07-07 11:10:24.343518+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111688] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2017-07-07 11:10:24.343758+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111688] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2017-07-07 11:10:25.109372+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111682] [] network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates
2017-07-07 11:10:25.334517+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111677] [] network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates
2017-07-07 11:10:25.445752+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111677] [] network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates
2017-07-07 11:10:25.553913+0900 MyBrowserApp[74215:10111676] [] network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates
```

Comment: macOSなのかiOSなのか(もしかしてtvOSかwatchOSか?はたまたLinux?)はタグを使うか本文中に明記していただいた方が良いでしょう。コードを見ればある程度は絞り込めますが、きちんと明示しておくことで、より多くの人たちにあなたの質問を閲覧してもらえるきっかけになります。さて、Xcodeからの起動で実行時エラーが生じた場合、エディター中の赤印とは別にデバッグコンソールにも何かしらのメッセージが出ているはずだと思うのですが、その情報をご質問に追記していただけますでしょうか。無理やり作った例だとこんなメッセージが表示されます: **`2017-07-06 16:01:00.771 ViewControllerMistype[65266:21911456] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fb57c40a9a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key button.'    *** First throw call stack: ...`**

Comment: @OOPer さん詳しいご指摘ありがとうございます。初めての質問でして、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @OOPer さん、使用OSはiOSです。コンソールのエラーは以下のようなものが表示されています。：
`2017-07-06 14:02:50.914542+0900 MyBrowserApp[68249:9976079] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fddae519980, _UIButtonBarStackView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
2017-07-06 14:02:50.920949+0900 MyBrowserApp[68249:9976079] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyBrowserApp.ViewController 0x7fddae50a4a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key goButton.'
*** First throw call stack:...`

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。ただ、コンソールエラーの内容はエラーを解決するのに本質的で極めて重要なものですので、コメントではなくご質問の本文中に追記いただけますでしょうか。ご自身の質問は「編集」ボタンが有効になっているはずです。

Comment: ストーリーボードで設定しているであろうアクションとアウトレットを全て削除して改めて接続を張り直してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @OOPerさん, @ura14hさん、返信ありがとうございます。接続をやり直しても同様のエラーが発生するので、コメントにエラーアラートを追加させていただきました。ご教授していただけると幸いです。

Comment: ご質問の編集ご苦労様でした。ただ、ご質問中に記載いただいたエラーメッセージは「SIGABRT」の原因ではないように思われます。ura14hさんの示唆されたようにストーリーボードの接続をやり直したら、 **`'[<MyBrowserApp.ViewController 0x7fddae50a4a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key goButton.'`** の部分は出力されなくなったと言うことでしょうか?

Comment: 説明不足ですいません。そうですね、やり直した結果ビルドが成功し「SIGABRT」エラーは出なくなりました。ただ、「top layout deprecated since ios 11.0」と「bottom layout deprecated since ios 11.0」アラートが出ます。これらはあまり気にする必要がないのでしょうか？

Comment: 元質問の最大ポイントであったSIGABRTについては、解消できたと言うことですね。「top layout deprecated since ios 11.0」と「bottom layout deprecated since ios 11.0」の警告は、Autolayoutを使用してXcodeのおすすめ通りに制約を追加するとよく発生します。deprecatedは即座に廃止を意味するものではないので一旦無視してもiOS11では動くでしょうが、気になるのであればInterface Builder上で制約を手動で貼り直す(top layoutとbottom layoutは使用しないように)ことで解消できます。

Comment: 調べたのですが、SIGABRTはUI部品をctrl+ドラッグでコードにドラッグした後に変数名を変更したことが原因で出たと思われます。なるほど、一度試してみます！しょうもない質問に丁寧にお答えいただきありがとうございました！

Comment: 最初のSIGABRTの原因もわかったようですね。できれば時間をとって原因と解決方法を、「回答」の形で書いてみてください。`NSUnknownKeyException`が原因で起こるSIGABRTに関するQAはすでにここ日本語版スタックオーバーフローにもいくつかあるのですが、少々条件が異なっていますので、SIGABRTの解消だけをポイントにした回答があれば、今後同じエラーで悩んでいる方々の役に立つだろうと思います。

Comment: 了解しました！徐々にStackoverflowの使い方にも慣れていきます！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

SIGABRTはUI部品をctrl+ドラッグでコードにドラッグした後に変数名を変更したことが原因で出たと‌​思われます。
ストーリーボードで設定しているであろうアクションとアウトレットを全て削除して改めて接続を張り直してみると問題解消は解消しました。その後にまだ出続ける「top layout deprecated since ios 11.0」と「bottom layout deprecated since ios 11.0」の警告は、Autolayoutで制約を追加した際によく発生するそうで、Interf‌​ace Builder上で制約を手動で貼り直す(top layoutとbottom layoutは使用しないように)ことで解消できるそうです。

Comment: ご回答の投稿ありがとうございます。質問を投稿してから一定時間経つとご自身での回答を承認(問題の解決に一番役立った回答であることを示すもの)することができます。ぜひ承認の操作もお願いします。なお、原因とその後の警告に対する内容は記載されていますが、解消方法そのもの(ura14hさんのコメントの内容)が回答中にありません。コメントは補助的な情報として大変有用なものですが、QAサイトとしてはコメントを追わなくても解決方法がわかるようにしておきたいものです。ご自身の回答も編集できるはずですので、追加した方が良いと思われる内容は、ぜひ編集して追加してみてください。

Comment: 補足ですがあなたがコメントに示されたメッセージの中で、この部分 **`this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key goButton.`** に`goButton`と言うのが出てきています。これはストーリーボード(またはxib)から`goButton`と言うIBOutletを(key value codingというのを使って)接続しようと思ったら、`goButton`がクラスの方には定義されていない、と言うことを表しています。大量のメッセージの中から有用な情報を抜き取るには慣れが必要ですが、少し勘所を覚えると「全て削除して改めて接続」するよりは、早く問題が解消できる可能性があります。一般的に`exception`とか`fatal error`とかのメッセージはよくチェックしておいた方が良いと思ってください。